# Determining number of students in each level

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, user-input

I am new to JAVA and Netbeans. This is what I have to do:
Display the numbers of students in each of the Levels (R, 1, 2, 3, 4).

```
Level R (mark < 50)     
Level 1 ( (mark >= 50) && (mark < 60) )    
Level 2 ( (mark >= 60) && (mark < 70) )    
Level 3 ( (mark >= 70) && (mark < 80) )    
Level 4 (mark >= 80).
```

I need to use an array and I know that it needs to contain 5 elements. I have no idea how to do this. BUT, I am not expecting to know the entire code from you so dont close the question. All I want to know is a hint or a method, so I know how to write the program. I appreciate any help and thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have no idea how to do a basic programming task, you've come to the wrong site.

Comment: I know there are nice people here who can help me with this

Comment: I'm sure there are. Doesn't mean you should take advantage of them.

Comment: Advantage? Read the question. I said I dont need the entire answer

Comment: Also, this site is meant more as a public resource than for individual assistance. Even if someone provides an answer, it's not a useful resource that benefits the site as a whole.

Comment: what is mark supposed to represent? and what are you hoping to contain in your array, numbers or letters?

Comment: Trying to contain numbers and to mark is supposed to be input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you started

```
    Point2D levelContainer[] = new Point2D[5];
    //set the R level
    levelContainer[0] = new Point2D.Double(0, 50);
    //set the rest
    levelContainer[1] = new Point2D.Double(50, 60);
    levelContainer[2] = new Point2D.Double(60, 70);
    levelContainer[3] = new Point2D.Double(70, 80);
    levelContainer[4] = new Point2D.Double(80, Double.MAX_VALUE);

    double exampleMark[] = {2, 56, 63, 70, 8080};

    for(int index = 0; index < exampleMark.length; index++)
    {
        //now for every mark we have, we need to loop the level array until we find the which level it falls in
        for(int levelIndex = 0; levelIndex < levelContainer.length; levelIndex++)
        {
            //now check the X, our minimum value, and the Y,our max value, for our range and if it does fall into the range print out the level
            if(exampleMark[index] >= levelContainer[levelIndex].getX() && exampleMark[index] < levelContainer[levelIndex].getY())
            {
                //basically use R if the level the mark falls into is 0
                String level = levelIndex == 0 ? "R" : new Integer(levelIndex).toString();
                System.out.println("Our current mark is " + exampleMark[index] + " which falls between " 
                        + levelContainer[levelIndex].getX() + " and " +
                        levelContainer[levelIndex].getY() + " which is level " + level);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Way too hard to understand but appreciate your help and it also gives me some errors

Comment: did you import the libraries..? if you import the libraries this all works fine